# node.js - async.each array item sort order automatically changing

Tags: node.js, synchronization, sails.js

i am using node.js with asyn library(https://github.com/caolan/async). When i use async.each function its working well but it changing the array item orders so i cant list the categories with some sorting..

```
        module.exports = {


           index: function (req, res) {
            var async = require('async');
            var data = new Object();

            data.title            = "";     
            data.meta_keywords    = "";     
            data.meta_description     = "";
            data.category         = new Array();

            bredcrumbs = new Array();
            bredcrumbs[0] = {'text':'Home','link':'Link','active':false};
            category_list = new Array();
            categories = new Array();

            async.waterfall([
                function(callback){
                    Category.find({sort: 'name ASC'}).done(function(err,cat_data){
                        //console.log(cat_data); 
                        categories = cat_data;
                        callback(null);
                    });
                },
                function(callback){

                    async.each(categories, SaveData, function(err){
                        // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
                        callback(null);
                    });
                },
            ], function () {
                data.category = category_list;
                //console.log(category_list);
                res.view('pages/home',data);
            });

            function SaveData(item,callback){ 
                Word.count({category_id:item['id'],status:'1',is_approved:'1'}).done(function(err, total){ 
                    t_category              = new Array();
                    t_category['name']      = item['name'];
                    t_category['keyword']   = item['keyword'];
                    t_category['link']      = "http://"+req.headers.host+"/game/"+item['keyword'];
                    t_category['total']     = total;
                    category_list.push(t_category);
                    callback(null);
                });
            }

          },
          /**
           * Overrides for the settings in `config/controllers.js`
           * (specific to HomeController)
           */
          _config: {}  
        };
```

i am using async.each function

```
      async.each(categories, SaveData, function(err){
                    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
                    callback(null);
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async.each() is NOT executing SaveData() in series so you might want to use async.eachSeries() if you want to keep the items of the new array (category_list) in the same order as the original array (categories).

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Note, that since this function applies the iterator to each item in parallel there is no guarantee that the iterator functions will complete in order.

Why don't you just sort the array after processing?

Example:

```
function compareByName(row1, row2) {
    if (row1.name > row2.name) {
        return 1;
    }
    return row1.name === row2.name ? 0 : -1;
}

categories.sort(compareByName);
```

Or if you don't have to press the last milliseconds out the request, you could use `eachSeries` instead.

BTW I think you should replace many of your `new Array()` by `{}`.